# Spring minified script caching with thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, spring, caching, thymeleaf

I am trying to configure springboot app. with config class to cache minified versions of javascript files.

Config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        VersionResourceResolver versionResourceResolver = new VersionResourceResolver()
                .addVersionStrategy(new ContentVersionStrategy(), "/**");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/images/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/js/")
                .setCachePeriod(60 * 60 * 24 * 7).resourceChain(true).addResolver(versionResourceResolver);
    }
}
```

html:

```
<head>
..
<script th:src="${@mvcResourceUrlProvider.getForLookupPath('/js/user.min.js')}" />
..
</head>
```

Spring should send a cookie with cache parameters but it doesn't, however if I am using the non minified version of **user.js** then the browser cache it successfully:

```
<head>
 ..
 <script th:src="${@mvcResourceUrlProvider.getForLookupPath('/js/user.js')}" />
 ..
</head>
```

The js resource files are next to each other under src/main/resources/static/js folder. They are working perfectly whether cached or not.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Strangely the solution was really easy....instead of

```
.setCachePeriod(60 * 60 * 24 * 7)
```

I have to use (with a little refactor):

```
.setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(7, TimeUnit.DAYS)).resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"));
```